# Как получить аватарку пользователя vk_api python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, изображения, photo

Столкнулся с проблемой - аватарку пользователя получить могу(https://vk.com/dev/users.get) , но она получается "прямоугольная", а не "круглая", как в сообщениях. Помогите, как получить "круглую"???

P.S. программирую на python

Comment: Аватарки пользователей прямоугольные, если перейти на страницу.

Comment: Круглых аватарок на серверах ВК нет, квадратные аватарки округляются на клиентах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел такой код, вроде рабочий) :

```
from PIL import ImageDraw,Image
def crop_img(profile_img,output):

    def prepare_mask(size, antialias = 2):
        mask = Image.new('L', (size[0] * antialias, size[1] * antialias), 0)
        ImageDraw.Draw(mask).ellipse((0, 0) + mask.size, fill=255)
        return mask.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    def crop(im, s):
        w, h = im.size
        k = w / s[0] - h / s[1]
        if k > 0: im = im.crop(((w - h) / 2, 0, (w + h) / 2, h))
        elif k < 0: im = im.crop((0, (h - w) / 2, w, (h + w) / 2))
        return im.resize(s, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    size = (140, 140)

    im = Image.open(profile_img)
    im = crop(im, size)
    im.putalpha(prepare_mask(size, 4))
    im.save(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

mask = Image.open('mask.png').convert('L')
im = Image.open('image.png')
output = ImageOps.fit(im, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
output.putalpha(mask)
output.save('output.png')
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890051/how-do-i-generate-circular-thumbnails-with-pil

Comment: А в том комменте с кодом на тостере написано что источником является ответ с стека: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890051/how-do-i-generate-circular-thumbnails-with-pil :)

Comment: Спасибо. Отредактировал.

Comment: Могли бы код и не менять, тем более, что тот код из тостера находился ниже кода, что сейчас вы привели в ответе, т.е. верните код из `If you want the thumbnail size to be variable you can use the ImageDraw and draw the mask.`, а то текущий код сложнее стал -- нужно еще файл маски использовать...

Answer (score 0):

Нужно самостоятельно "скруглить" картинку. Это можно сделать через маску

[Привожу пример кода:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22336005/5909792)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.open('input.jpg')
bigsize = img.size[0] * 3, img.size[1] * 3
mask = Image.new('L', bigsize, 0)

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
draw.ellipse((0, 0) + bigsize, fill=255)

mask = mask.resize(img.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.putalpha(mask)
img.save('output.png')
```

---

input.jpg:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

output.png:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]